How to setup influxDB testcontainer with token
I'm trying to spin-up an influxDB testcontainer to run my integration test with.
@Container
static InfluxDBContainer<?> influxDBContainer = new InfluxDBContainer<>(
        DockerImageName.parse("influxdb:2.0.7")
)
        .withAuthEnabled(true);

My app do authorisation via token, not via user/password.
The question is how may I set-up the needed token in the container on startup.
is it possible to do smth like
.withEnv("INFLUX_TOKEN", "test-token");?

Just use a Docker compose file and point your Spring project to the right file, like explained in the Spring DOCs
:
spring.docker.compose.file=../my-compose.yml

Look up the InfluxDB docker image DOCs for the configuration you need. Minimal example:
services:
  time-series-database:
    # Change to your version of choice - https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb/tags
    image: influxdb:2.7-alpine
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8086:8086
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=john-doe
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=my-super-secret-password
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=acme-inc
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=my-bucket
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=0YVmO2e179ymcr4AZoA9FOEAIZSdDmezA8yIuLnSL4ERowgKZGKWEKqZAR64BCVn1aC4tN6Jq7aVM0ldAMZJIQ==


INFLUX_TOKEN is not an env var supported by indluxdb image. Once the containers has started, commands can be executed to create a token.
influxDBContainer.execInContainer("influx", "auth", "create"...);

Source: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/admin/tokens/create-token/#create-a-token-using-the-influx-cli
